# How to show different selection fields in two menus using the same MODEL in Odoo 13 enterprise?

Tags: model, field, odoo-13

I got two menus using the same MODEL.

In the first menu: Books (Sổ Bảo Hiểm), I will show all the related fields like this (1.png)

[image: All relevant fields are displayed]

But in the second menu: History change (Lịch Sử Thay Đổi), I want to hide "Pipeline status bar" field (2.png)

[image: Hide the pipeline status bar field]

How to do that?
Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add a sample code of how you're passing the two views

Comment: You can do it by using Studio tool, you know.